# Stationary Test issue

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, forecasting

I am working with **air miles** data set and i conducted three different tests to check for stationary in the time series data set

Test 1: Using acf and pacf

```
acf(airmiles)
```

[image]

```
pacf(airmiles)
```

[image]

After differentiating its seems most of the values lies in significance level now

```
acf(diff(airmiles))
pacf(diff(airmiles))
```

[image][image]

Test 2: Using adf.test

```
adf.test(airmiles,k=0,alternative = "stationary")


    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  airmiles
Dickey-Fuller = -1.1415, Lag order = 0, p-value = 0.8994
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

p-value seems to be greater than 0.05 so i differentiate and then conduct same test

```
adf.test(diff(airmiles),k=0,alternative = "stationary")


    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  diff(airmiles)
Dickey-Fuller = -5.4406, Lag order = 0, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

and so value is less now but in case of kpss.test

```
kpss.test(diff(airmiles))   KPSS Test for Level Stationarity

data:  diff(airmiles) KPSS Level = 0.83442, Truncation lag parameter = 1, p-value = 0.01
```

The p-value is already less than 0.05 and i am concerned about which tests should i actually work with and which one leads to a better model at the end.

Comment: As far as I remember the Null of KPSS is that the ts IS stationary (unlike ADF). You might want to double check that.

Comment: @r.user.05apr thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

A differencing model with an AR1 and 2 outliers dealing with period 10 and 22 would be a good model. Notice there is no constant.
[image]